# Correct shell program for entrypoint into golang alpine docker container?

Tags: docker, go

I'm trying to spin up a golang alpine docker container (just the basic image) and immediately connect to it to run commands, but I can't seem to specify the correct shell program.

```
docker run -d golang:1.20-alpine --entrypoint=bin/sh
ec90a5d5eeba63e509acc09e234054d883aa122cd7617f89b61e7d71220847cd
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "--entrypoint=bin/sh": stat --entrypoint=bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

I've also tried: `/bin/sh`. What am I missing here?

Comment: I did `docker pull golang:1.20-alpine`, then `docker run -id --name=test5 golang:1.20-alpine`, and then `docker exec -it test5 /bin/sh`. I was in. Can you try that sequence of commands and see if it works well for you? I also ran `docker run -it golang:1.20-alpine /bin/sh` and that worked just fine also.

Comment: You could also change your command slightly to: `docker run -d --entrypoint=/bin/sh golang:1.20-alpine`

Comment: `bin/sh` is not `/bin/sh`. The leading `/` is necessary to have an absolute path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just write an answer instead of commands in comments.

To spin up a golang alpine docker container (just the basic image) and immediately connect to it to run commands, you can do this:

```
docker run -it golang:1.20-alpine /bin/sh
```

If you want to name your container, you could do this:

```
docker pull golang:1.20-alpine
docker run -id --name=test5 golang:1.20-alpine
docker exec -it test5 /bin/sh
```

You can stop the container with `docker stop test5 -t 2` and start it up again using `docker start test5`.

You can remove it by doing `docker rm test5`.

---

You can change your command just a little bit to avoid the error:

```
docker run -d --entrypoint=/bin/sh golang:1.20-alpine
```

Notice that the `--entrypoint` command line switch is before golang:1.20-alpine.